# Link to external URL

Tags: permalinks

Only information I found on this were hacks 6+ years ago or plugins. Quite simply, I want to grab a URL (www.google.com) from a custom post type and make a link that links to that URL.

Currently, my links just go to

> www.mysite.com/mypage/www.google.com

```
$url = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'ext_url', true);
return '<div">
            <a href="' . $url . '">External</a>
       </div>';
```

Comment: What do you get when you do a `var_dump` on `$url` like `var_dump( '$url' );`

Comment: string(14) "www.google.com"

Comment: you need `http://` or it is interpreted as a relative url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `http://` in front, your code won't work. You will need to add that infront. You can make use of [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to add `http://` to urls that does not have that.

To make this protocol agnostic, you can simply use `//`

You can try something like this

```
$urlStr = 'www.google.com';
$parsed = parse_url($urlStr);
if ( empty( $parsed['scheme'] ) ) {
    $urlStr = '//' . ltrim( $urlStr, '/' );
}
echo '<a href="' . $urlStr . '">External</a>';
```

Comment: consider updating this to make it protocol agnostic - aka change `http://` to simply `//`

Comment: I've learnt something new with `parse_url()`. +1